# Most efficient way to determine subgraph by x,y coordinate limits?

Tags: networkx

For graphs with coordinate information for each node in NetworkX I would like to be able to create subgraphs providing x, y limits `[(min_x, max_x), (min_y, max_y)]`.
Do I need to extract all coordinates and manually check them against my constraints with

```
list(zip(*graph.nodes(data = "pos")))
```

Or is there a more direct or simple way to solve this task?

Thank you very much in advance.
me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [subgraph view](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/classes/generated/networkx.classes.graphviews.subgraph_view.html) of networkx. So, something like:

```
def select_by_coords(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):
    def inner_select(node):
        node_dict = dict(node)
        return xmin < node_dict['x'] < xmax && ymin < node_dict['y'] < ymax
    
    return inner_select

subgraph = subgraph_view(graph, filter_node=select_by_coords(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))
```